# how to run/start graphical programs (Ex: firefox) on a remote machine using CLI without logging in

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg, xvfb, xserver

So, the story is like this:

I have 2 linux machines with ubuntu **20.04** installed on both. one of them, call it computer A doesn't have X on it because it is the server version installed and I don't want to install it.

So I am connecting to **computerB** from **computerA** via **SSH**. **ComputerB** is not logged in and I don't want to log onto it graphically/visually.

But what I am trying to achieve is start a program on **computerB** while I am connected via **ssh** from **computerA**.

I have found that **Xvfb** works for me in doing what I want but I don't understand why do I need it. Is there no other way except installing this test **X server** ?
Sorry for my ignorance, I am a novice in X matters.

Comment: if you want to run browser periodically without the need to see what browser displays then try headless mode of chrome or firefox.

Comment: firefox is just an example, I have my own app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like using Xvfb is the only option since not logging in is not desired/ an option.